# How to convert XML to XSL-FO?

Tags: java, pdf-generation

What is the easiest way to convert XML or HTML to XSL_FO?

I have tried different things but failed to parse.

please let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: @helderdarocha --  I should have framed my question in a better way..I will post  another question related to this in 10 mins with my code

Comment: You need a rendering engine.  For these purposes XSL/FO is similar to PDF.